# dont understand with func printf in C

Tags: c

This code:

```
char arr1[20] = "fedcba";
char *ptr;

ptr = &arr1[2];
puts(arr1);
printf("%d\n",*arr1 - *ptr);
printf("%d\n",arr1 - ptr);
```

I understand that the first printing puts the string.

printf I - what is supposed to print? It says * arr1 - * ptr?

printf II - What is the difference between one and two?

Answer (score 3):

The first prints the difference between 2 `char`s:

The second prints the difference between 2 pointers.

`*arr1` dereferences a `char*` and returns the first character, which is `'f'`.

`ptr = &arr1[2];` will make `ptr` point to `"dcba"`. It takes the address of the third character in `arr1`. `*ptr` returns `'d'`.

So the first `printf` returns the difference between characters `f` and `d` - which is `2`.

The second one is the difference between the two pointers. It's legal since they both point inside the same character array. It's the same as `arr1 - &arr[2]` which will most likely be `-2`, since arrays are stored continuously in memory.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%d\n",*arr1 - *ptr);
```

This prints the result of the first character of `arr1` minus the first character of `ptr`. 
Here is clearer version that does the same thing: `printf("%d\n",arr1[0] - ptr[0]);`

---

```
printf("%d\n",arr1 - ptr);
```

This prints the pointer difference between `arr1` and `ptr`, which is 2.

Essentially the property holds that: `(a[x] - a)` is equivalent to `x`

Comment: ptr points at the third character in arr1 so the behavior of the second printf is not undefined!

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two lines to your program for better understanding...

```
printf("\n%d AND %d... %c",arr1, *arr1, *arr1);
printf("\n%d AND %d... %c",ptr, *ptr, ptr[0] ); //ptr[0] == *ptr
```

Hope this helps...